# App crash NSDate message sent to deallocated instance?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsdate, nszombie

When I launch my app it crashes and I'm getting this error :

[image]

and after enabling Zombies object I get this error in log :

> -[__NSDate dealloc]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x16765ce0

**Update :**

I used Profile (Cmd + I) and i choosed NSZombie with xcode and i got this :

[image]

My code where i user fliclib is :

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import FBSDKLoginKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        FlicAuth.sharedInstance
        return true
    }
}
```

And

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

class FlicAuth: NSObject, SCLFlicManagerDelegate, SCLFlicButtonDelegate {
    static let sharedInstance = FlicAuth()
    var flicButton: SCLFlicButton!
    var flicButtons = [SCLFlicButton]()
    var flicError: Int!

    override init() {
        super.init()

        SCLFlicManager.configureWithDelegate(self, defaultButtonDelegate: self, appID: FlicAppId, appSecret: FlicAppSecret, backgroundExecution: false)

    }

    func requestButton(){
        SCLFlicManager.sharedManager()?.grabFlicFromFlicAppWithCallbackUrlScheme("grabButton")
    }

    func flicManager(manager: SCLFlicManager, didGrabFlicButton button: SCLFlicButton?, withError error: NSError?) {
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error: \(error!.domain) - \(error!.code)")
            return
        }

        button?.delegate = self
        button?.triggerBehavior = .ClickAndDoubleClickAndHold
        button?.connect()
        flicButtons.append(button!)
    }
}
```

My fliclib : https://github.com/50ButtonsEach/fliclib-ios

Any idea why I'm getting the nsdate problem ?

Comment: The code you shared doesn't seem to use any NSDates.

Comment: Yes that's what i'm not understanding, I added the link of my fliclib in my post